# At which point a TCP connection is established while making XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

HTTP works on top of TCP. So,a TCP connection must be established before making any HTTP request. I was learning AJAX, and the simple code that mkaes a HTTP request in AJAX is like this:

```
 function doGET()
{
   var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() //This part is actually executed last
    {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) // Was the request processed successfully?
       {    
        document.getElementById("sampleDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxTest2.php?sampleVar=" + Math.random());
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Please help me to understand at which point TCP is established?

Comment: after `.send()` - oh, wait, you want the anatomy of a HTTP request? http://blog.catchpoint.com/2010/09/17/anatomyhttp/

Comment: So, this happens simultaneously in one step? with `.send()` , first **TCP**  is established then it makes a  **HTTP** request?

Comment: I can't see how you can establish a TCP connection AFTER you send a HTTP request. TCP obeys the laws of space/time. It'd be like taking a road trip and arriving at your destination before you even start the car!

Comment: `simultaneously in one step` well, no, it takes a measurable amount of time - but as far as javascript is concerned, the request is made by `.send()`, there is no other "step" involved, so in this frame of reference, it is a single step - what happens beyond javascript is of no interest to javascript at this point

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks! your last comment helped, but I'm interested to know more about the steps `.open()` and `.send()`. A link would be helpful.